# Dynamic Generation of Items in listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am trying to populate items in a listview based on what the user types in an edit text box. For eg: If there are a list of cars and bikes, if the user types cars in the edit text, the listview should only populate car names and not bikes. Please tell me how to proceed with this. Should i use a custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

[This guy is great](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka5Tk7J9rG0) and he has many tutorials on listview. In short it sounds like you need [a collection](http://www.javatpoint.com/collections-in-java) to store listview items you want to display. You populate this collection from a [content provider](https://github.com/foxykeep/ContentProviderCodeGenerator) or other datasource  by running [a query](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-ContentResolver-query.htm) from your edittext value and [implement](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) the listview as normal. If you only display strings no need for custom adapter or extending baseadapter.

Comment: so i cant do this with a simple if else statement? Like if('EditText variable'.getText.toString()=="honda") then populate those items alone

Comment: Possibly, my point is you need a data source of some kind (contentprovider,List<String>) a temporary place to store query results, the edit text and listview. How you do this depends. How many items are in the datasource? Is the datasource local or from the cloud? is data dynamic, changing over time or fixed, static. How big is the datasource? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The datasource is local and it is fixed. Lets just say i am going to make a list of items on my own and store it in an array list ( say 10 strings of both cars and bike names). Now can you give me an example code? I want to make it as simple as possible,Thank you

Comment: I would be grateful if someone can give me an example. Thanks!